# What triggered the war between the Autobots and Decepticons?

Tags: transformers

Is a definitive reason ever given as to what triggered the civil war on Cybertron?

I know Decepticons are evil and Autobots are good, but what triggered the war to begin with? What is it about the beliefs of the two groups that makes them unable to come to some sort of permanent truce?

In the film versions, it is not really touched upon, and I am pretty sure the cartoons I have watched also don't go into what triggered the war.

Comment: In which continuity? The comics and the [various TV shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Transformers_television_series), films, games and the [various other media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers) aren't in agreement.

Comment: Why can't we talk to the Decepticons? A little understanding could make things better.

Comment: If they weren't fighting, it would sell less plastic tat from China, hence the war rages on eternally.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite starscream or megatron?  the former smiles ant talks to you and then shoots you into teh back.  and the later gets amused laughs and outright rips you apart.

Comment: [curly straw](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Curly_straw)

Comment: "I know Deceptcons are evil and Autobots are good" Well, that's what the Autobots propagandists would have us believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Transformers G1 (The original 1984 series) the war on Cybertron was described in Episode 38 ["Desertion of the Dinobots, Part 2"](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Desertion_of_the_Dinobots,_Part_2) like this:

> Millions of years ago, Cybertron was a planet of peace...until the
>   Decepticons, lusting for power, began a terrible war. Not designed for
>   combat, the Autobots were overwhelmed and subjugated by their evil
>   opponents. While many Autobots fled Cybertron, a few valiant survivors
>   devised new tactics and launched a counter-offensive on their
>   arch-foes. And thus began a terrible series of wars. Many times, both
>   sides have claimed victory, but this has been short-lived, for the
>   Autobots have overthrown Decepticon tyrants, and, likewise, Decepticon
>   treachery has toppled many a peaceful Autobot ruler. And to this day,
>   the war rages on.

The Quintessons made the Transformers originally, though they didn't transform then, and the Transformers eventually turned on the Quintessons and drove them off the planet.
[Source](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Cybertronian_Civil_Wars#Generation_1_cartoon_continuity)

> After the slaves drove the Quintessons away from Cybertron, peace
>   reigned. However, the division between consumer goods and military
>   hardware was becoming acute, as the two groups had even named
>   themselves differently: The consumer goods robots called themselves
>   Autobots, and the military hardware robots were known as Decepticons.
>   While the Autobots preferred a peaceful existence, the Decepticons
>   wanted conquest. For a time, the Decepticons succeeded.

The Autobots then developed transformation and the guardian robots to defend themselves, and that was known as the 'Golden Age of Cybertron':

The Matrix was already in existence at this point, apparently being passed from one Autobot leader to the next, as is the practice today.

> The Autobots couldn't match the brute strength of the Decepticons, so
>   they turned to stealth, learning the art of transformation. Using this
>   new technology, they defeated the Decepticons and ruled for many
>   centuries in a "Golden Age." Peace was kept with the use of Guardian
>   robots (presumably based upon the Quintessons' Dark Guardians),
>   sentinels that protected cities, quelled uprisings, and generally did
>   the dirty work of war. However, the Decepticons eventually learned to
>   transform and also developed some form of anti-gravity that allowed
>   them to fly without the use of jets. They also built a powerful leader
>   for themselves: Megatron.

Comment: so, no reason other than "lust for power" ?

Comment: Yeah basically. In G1 at least.

Comment: @Max in other continuities the decepticon leader.....thinks conquest is the only way for them to survive,.... so depends on continuity

Comment: "so they turned to stealth, learning the art of transformation" So, one side learned how to trick those other side into thinking they were something they're not ... and the other side is called "Decepticons"?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes well the Autobots made friends with the Humans first, so therefore they get to write the propoganda. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "in a "Golden Age." Peace was kept with the use of Guardian robots (presumably based upon the Quintessons' Dark Guardians), sentinels that protected cities, quelled uprisings, and generally did the dirty work of war." I am starting to agree, the autobots sound like dangerous commie dictators, who want earth thinking the "decepticons" are bad :)